# Where is the error inside this code?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The code below create one circle inside the windows form.
This code compiled without any errors. But it didn't draw the ellipse?! Why?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class Task1 : Form1
    {
        public void FillEllipseInt(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            SolidBrush redBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            int x = 100;
            int y = 100;
            int width = 200;
            int height = 100;
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(redBrush, x, y, width, height);
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `FillEllipseInt` is never called.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa327623%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach the `Paint` event of the form and from that call your `FillEllipseInt` method. Also, you need to change `Application.Run(new Form1());` to `Application.Run(new Task1());` as (at least in the code you've shown) there's not `Form1` class. This is also why I think that `Task1` should inherit from `Form` and not `Form1`.

Comment: How do I attach the Paint event?

Comment: Open the form in the Windows forms designer, go to the "Properties" dockable window, select the "Events" tab in the properties window and double click the "Paint" event.

Comment: Ok. All work))) Thanks a lot. But as I understood, I need to place code that draw a circle in the form1.cs

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Is `Task1` the form or is `Form1` the form? Why does `Task1` inherit from `Form1` and why does it contain the main method instead of `Program.cs` containing the main method? You see, you didn't provide enough information about your project structure to answer the question

Comment: Ok. I knew that I didn't give you enough information. I'm newbie. This is my first experience. Thanks a lot. I'll try to continue read books about C#)

Answer (score 1):

You have created the instance of Form1 instead of Task 1

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

You also need to create the instance of Task1

```
Application.Run(new Task1())
```

Comment: Ok, but it's not draw a circle?!